# unknown field "selector" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I would like to create a cronjob in Kubernetes cluster. I got errors. It seems like errors in my yaml file. But I have no clue what the correct syntax is.

kubectl apply -f converter-86-cron.yaml

error: error validating "converter-86-cron.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec): unknown field "selector" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

code:

```
  apiVersion: batch/v1
  kind: CronJob
  metadata:
    name: converter-86-cron
    namespace: converter
  spec:
    schedule: "0 10 * * *" # 3 AM PST
    jobTemplate:
      spec:
        template:
          metadata:
            namespace: converter
            labels:
              name: converter-86-cron
          spec:
            selector:
              matchLabels:
                architecture: "8.6"
            containers:
              - name: convert
                image: "accountID.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/converter:1.1.1b9.2004.cu114.12345668"
                resources:
                  requests:
                    nvidia.com/gpu: 1
                    cpu: 2
                  limits:
                    nvidia.com/gpu: 1
                args:
                - python3
                - trt-converter.py
                - --awsdev
            tolerations:
            - key: "nvidia.com/gpu"
              operator: "Exists"
              effect: "NoSchedule"
            restartPolicy: Never
```

New code with nodeSelector. Not sure if it is correct.

```
  apiVersion: batch/v1
  kind: CronJob
  metadata:
    name: converter-86-cron
    namespace: converter
  spec:
    schedule: "0 10 * * *" # 3 AM PST
    jobTemplate:
      spec:
        template:
          metadata:
            namespace: converter
            labels:
              name: converter-86-cron
          spec:
            nodeSelector:
              architecture: "8.6"
            containers:
              - name: convert
                image: "accountID.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/converter:1.1.1b9.2004.cu114.12345668"
                resources:
                  requests:
                    nvidia.com/gpu: 1
                    cpu: 2
                  limits:
                    nvidia.com/gpu: 1
                args:
                - python3
                - trt-converter.py
                - --awsdev
            tolerations:
            - key: "nvidia.com/gpu"
              operator: "Exists"
              effect: "NoSchedule"
            restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: How is the question related to `kubernetes-helm`? --- While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read `CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec` as a tree..
so under CronJob -> spec -> jobTemplate and so on...
so in your case the `selector:` under `spec:` at line 16 above is the invalid field.

You should refer to documentation on how exactly or where exactly you should put the selector/label and architecture.

Comment: This is the problem. I read the doc at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#example. I did not find out where I can place selector. The doc does not explain it.

Comment: Wrong doc. Take a look at [this one (`kubernetes.io`)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/cron-job-v1/).

Comment: I have nodes labeled as architecture: "8.6". I want the Cronjob runs on those nodes. I found labelSelector from the doc you provided. But, I guess I should use nodeSelector? I posted my new code above. Is it correct?